# Scatter plot with conditional coloring of certain points in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I'm plotting two pieces of data that I care about, **medv** and **lstat**.

I have plotted these two already using boxplots, they are called **lstatBox** and **medvBox**. The reason I have done this is because I want access to the outliers of these two sets of data.

Accessing the outlier values is done as such...

```
>lstatBox$out
[1] 34.77 34.37 34.41 34.02 36.98 37.97 

>medvBox$out    
[1] 50.0 43.1 39.8 50.0 43.5 50.0 50.0 50.0 46.7 50.0 48.3 50.0 50.0 50.0 48.5 42.3 37.6 37.9 50.0 41.7 41.3 50.0 50.0 46.0
[25] 48.8 50.0 38.7 50.0 45.4 37.2 44.0 43.8 37.3 42.8 50.0 44.8 50.0
```

I can currently make a scatterplot just by doing this....

```
plot(medv,lstat)
```

BUT, i would like the outlier values for each class to be a different color. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create an array of outlier colors:

```
outlier.colors <- (medv %in% medvBox$out)*1 + (lstat %in% lstatBox$out)*2
outlier.colors <- outlier.colors + 1

plot(medv, lstat, col=outlier.colors)
```

Comment: If you want to use named colors instead of numbers, use `ifelse` as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375977/using-conditional-statements-to-change-the-color-of-data-points